# Why *In medias res* and not *In media res*?

Tags: grammar-choice, idiom, translation-explanation

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res) gives literal translation as: *Into the middle of things*.

As far as I am aware **into** – *in* takes accusative.

Plural accusative of *medium* seems to be *media*, not *media**s***

Even if I am mistaken in this way of thinking, there seems to be no *medias* word in [declension table for *medium*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/medium#Latin).

Why does *in medias res* seem to be accepted form then?

Comment: What about “virtus est medium vitiorum” Horace Epistle I, 18 Si bene te novi ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are confusing two words:

- The noun *medium* means "center".
- The adjective *medius* means "central".

In this idiom one goes into "central things".
The word *res* is feminine (the singular nominative and plural accusative happen to look alike), so the adjective has to be in feminine plural accusative: *medias*.

If you were to use the noun *medium* instead, you might want to go into "the center of things".
Then you'd put *medium* in singular accusative (there's only one center, right?) and *res* in plural genitive.
This leads to the alternative *in medium rerum*.
This might be equally valid, but Latin does often prefer adjectives to nouns, and Horatius happened to write *in medias res*.

Using the adjective is probably more idiomatic and common than the noun, but the noun is not a non-Latin choice either.
See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2153/79) and its answer for an example from Vergilius, where the noun *medium* is used although the adjective *medius* would have been metrically equal.
Perhaps the adjective would not work here, as something happens between two things, not in the middle of one.
But I would still take it as evidence (perhaps weak!) that both *medius* and *medium* are appropriate in cases like yours.

Answer (score 9):

*Medias* is not a noun but an accusative of the adjective *medius* (middle or central) in agreement with the plural *res*. This is standard idiomatic usage, not just for this phrase. A spatial portion is [consistently expressed](https://books.google.com/books?id=rJgQAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA168&ots=ajZGEtmSgc&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q&f=false) (p. 168) in Latin with an adjective in a way that sounds wrong when taken word-for-word into English:

> 396. 'The whole of,' 'the middle of,' 'the top (bottom) of,' 'the rest of,' are expressed in Latin by adjectives agreeing with nouns (instead of the partitive genitive)

The alternative *in medium rerum* constructed by Joonas Ilmavirta (using the accusative noun *medium* and the genitive *rerum*) is the closest word-for-word to the English "into the middle of things", but is not "equally valid" based on the Latin usage rule.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I agree that the adjective *medius* is a far more idiomatic choice here.

Comment: Good answer. The construction is indeed common in Latin, but less common in English or various other modern languages. We call this figure of speech **enallage**, "interchange, transposition", or **hypallage**: it applies when an adjective is made to agree syntactically with a certain substantive (pro)noun, while semantically it belongs with another one. Dutch Wikipedia explains it well enough (the English one is i.m.o. strange or less accurate): https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enallage English Wikipaedia explains it under *hypallage*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage

Answer (score 2):

As the Latin preposition 'in' can govern either the accusative or the ablative case, depending on whether movement or place is expressed, it is grammatically correct to speak of (for example) an author plunging in medias res (into the midst of matters) to begin the presentation of a story, but (theoretically, at any rate) incorrect to say that a story begins in medias res as this is evidently place and not movement, and strictly should be in mediis rebus, the ablative form. But most people would dismiss this as pedantry, like trying to put status quo into the ablative.